# find people who have values in a specific date range but not in others

Tags: sql, subquery

I am querying a User based database, and trying to find people that have made purchases withing a certain date range only.

e.g:
bring back all the people that purchased only between `'2017-7-01'` and `'2017-08-01'` but have not purchased since.

I have tried:

```
select payment_id 
from table1 
where created_at between '2017-7-01' 
                     and '2017-08-01' 
  and not between '2017-7-01' and '2017-08-01';
```

and all kinds of variations on this.
I guess a subquery is in order here, but don't really know how to approach
hope someone can help :)

Thanks

Comment: You also need to change created_at between '2017-7-01' 
                     and '2017-08-01' 
  and not between '2017-7-01' and '2017-08-01'`  to                        created_at between '2017-7-01' 
                     and '2017-08-01' 
  and  created_at  not between '2017-7-01' and '2017-08-01'`

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: I was close! :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional `COUNT()` to see if user have any purchase in that date range and no purchase after the upper range limit.

Also you need something related to users, I guess `user_id` so you can group everything.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN created_at between '2017-07-01' 
                                      and '2017-08-01' 
                  THEN 1
             END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN created_at > '2017-08-01' 
                  THEN 1
             END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select payment_id
from (
    select payment_id 
    from table1 
    where created_at between '2017-7-01' and '2017-08-01' )
where created_at > '2017-08-01'
```

Comment: That doesnt work. Because in the inner query you already filter any `date > '2017-08-01'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select userid
From table1
Where userid not in (select userid from table1 where createdat between @startdate and @enddate)
Where createdat > @enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter ensuring the MAX(date) is less than 2017-08-01 then you can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`.
Ex.

```
select payment_id
from table1
where created_at between '2017-07-01' AND '2017-08-01'       
GROUP BY payment_id
HAVING MAX(created_at) < '2017-08-01' --most recent date less than requested date
```

Comment: Thanks! will that for the max created_at per each user?

Comment: It is grouping by payment_id, so it is the MAX(created_at) for the payment_id. I tested this with a temp table prior to posting the code it was giving the expected results.  It depends what payment_id represents, or if you wanted a user_id instead... you never mentioned user_id in your post and I see some answers now with user_id.  If that's the case, it should be `select user_id`, and `group by user_id`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.